# How to Write Java server logs to separate log file

Tags: java, web-applications, logging, log4j

Right now we are using a customized logger method for our application but now we have a stand alone code for which we need to write to a separate log file. We have little idea about log4j. I just want to know where to change properties if any so that i don't disturb the existing logger application as well as we  write our logs into new log file.

Answer (score 1):

First define a file appender:

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=/mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Then point your package to use this appender:

```
log4j.logger.mypackage=LOGFILE
log4j.additivity.mypackage=false
```

The last line is important if you do not want your package to inherit the global appender. Doing so will result in the log messages from mypackage also printed at the default appender.

Answer (score 1):

in log4j you can direct log entries to separate files based upon pacakge name.

log4j.logger.your.package1= LOG,STDOUT

log4j.additivity.your.package1=false

log4j.logger.your.package2= DEBUG, STDOUT

log4j.additivity.your.package2=false

Comment: you can define various logs as shown in the answer by "Kgiannakakis"

replace LOGFILE by LOG, DEBUG, etc

log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=/mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

Answer (score 1):

I use XML configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="app.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d-%5p(%F:%L)-%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="myLogfile" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="myFile.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d-%5p(%F:%L)-%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="org.myApp">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="myLogfile" />
</logger>
<root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) and specify a new filename in the constructor.